# Login sequence broken after upgrading to Spring Security 4

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm upgrading the dependencies of a Java Spring web application, upgrading from Spring Security 3 to 4. The login sequence broke. When the user clicks the login button, a POST is sent to /j_spring_security_check as it should.

However, the server simply returns a 302 redirect with the location set to "403". The browser then tries to access /403 and receives a 403 error, because the user is not logged in and can't access that URL.

I've followed the [Migration Guide](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html#m3to4-xmlnamespace-logout) and here is my updated `form-login`:

```
    <form-login login-page="/login" 
                authentication-failure-url="/login/failure"
                default-target-url="/"  
                always-use-default-target="true"
                username-parameter="j_username" 
                password-parameter="j_password" 
                login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was CSRF - the CSRF behavior has changed in Spring Security 4, and it is now enabled by default. I had to add `<csrf disabled="true">` to make the application work (I will obviously enable CSRF at a later stage, after everything works).

I just wonder why I didn't receive any CSRF related message, that would have saved me hours.